# My Tensorboard does not work, keep saying that 'No scalar data was found'

Tags: tensorflow, scalar, tensorboard

I'm pretty new to Tensorboard and would like to build one.
I followed exactly same procedure as someone already did and they said it worked, But on my machine it does not work.
I run Session and merge all summaries in the middle. 
Then, I use SummaryWriter to create an event under the folder /logs/test.
 In the for loop I add summary to the writer object.
 
When I tun 'tensorboard --logdir=/logs/test' I see nothing.....
I think there is nothing I miss and I really have no idea why this code does not work. 
Could anyone figure out?? Much appreciated!

The example code is below :

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

add = tf.add(X, Y)
mul = tf.mul(X, Y)

add_hist = tf.scalar_summary("add_scalar", add)
mul_hist = tf.scalar_summary("mul_scalar", mul)

merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    sess.run(init)

    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("./logs/test", sess.graph_def)

for step in range(100):
    sess.run(add, feed_dict = {X: step*1.0, Y: 2.0})

    summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict = {X: step*1.0, Y: 2.0})
    writer.add_summary(summary, step)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SummaryWriter](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter) buffers the events for performance, to minimize Disk I/O requests.
You are not closing the summary writer at the end and the number of events that you write is not enough to trigger the write to disk.
You can force to write the events to disk by using `SummaryWriter.flush`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

add = tf.add(X, Y)
mul = tf.mul(X, Y)

add_hist = tf.scalar_summary("add_scalar", add)
mul_hist = tf.scalar_summary("mul_scalar", mul)

merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    sess.run(init)

    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("./logs/test", sess.graph)

    for step in range(100):
        sess.run(add, feed_dict = {X: step*1.0, Y: 2.0})

        summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict = {X: step*1.0, Y: 2.0})
        writer.add_summary(summary, step)
        writer.flush()
    write.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out. I added writer.flush() and writer.close() and it still didn't work :(

Comment: how do you launch tensorboard? `tensorboard --logdir ./logs/test` from the same root path ?

Comment: Yes... :( I tried both tensorboard --logdir ./logs/test and tensorboard --logdir=./logs/test and neither worked. I really don't know why.. Do I need to run in different way to have that folder and then run tensor board? I thought when I execute that command it automatically creates events in that folder.

Comment: what version of tensorflow are you running?

Comment: My Tensorflow version is 0.10.0 and I'm a Mac user.

Comment: https://anaconda.org/jjhelmus/tensorflow is the website I referred to install Tensorflow